# How can I access same page in two different window that can manipulate data at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, angularjs, web-services

I'm having trouble with the features that I want to achieve in the project.

I just want to access same page in two different window / more. the reason why I'm doing this is to be able the user to do multitask, while one page is manipulating the data, other page can also be access.

I'v tried my best but still the page waits until the other one finished before other will load the data.

Please advise,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should be able to accomplish this with multiple "panels" on one page. No need for multiple pages. I guess you could do that with iFrames but I don't see why you'd really want to

Comment: I did this in the form of Jquery Dialog but the first dialog need to be finish before the second dialog proceed in executing the procedure. my client wants to do multitasking. it is like sending a message to many recipient, the objective is while one message is sending they can also create new message and can send it even the 1st one are still sending.

Comment: something like jquery tabs maybe - http://jqueryui.com/tabs/? run different task in separate tab...

Comment: what are you using to send the messages? The sending of the messages should be handled in the background while allowing the user to continue just like your email works.

Comment: @DelightedD0D, yes it was handled in background using webservice. this webservice has method that create records in sql DB and after that it will send the message. I used to store the recipient in array and loop them so it will perform the creation of record again and again until at the end of array.

Comment: @SET, I used Jquery Dialog, and I tried to do it in separate window which both doesn't work for me.

Comment: can use websockets for real time updates. If second window opened by same user can use postMessage also

Comment: @charlietfl, what I want to achieve is like, I have main interface which has a list of records there, each record you can forward them to many recipient. you'll see those recipient when you click one of the record on the main page. those are in the dialog. what I want is: I want to access again the popup even it was not yet finished in sending and I can send another with the second popup.

Comment: Explore this beauty https://www.firebase.com/